# Hide column in kendo ui using jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Been a while research, try to hide one specify column in kendo grid table

using this

```
 $('#grid .k-grid-content table tr td:nth-child(8),th:nth-child(8)').toggle();
```

with no help, anyone has ideas?

The column I want to hide bind to

```
              { 
                field: "CreatedDate",
                width: 20,
                title: "Create Date",
                type: 'date',

                template: '#= kendo.toString(CreatedDate,"MM/dd/yyyy") #'
            }
```

[edited]

```
$('#grid div.k-grid-header-wrap th:nth-child(4)').toggle()
$('#grid div.k-grid-content td:nth-child(4)').toggle()
```

can only hide the header..but not the whole column, still need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#grid div.k-grid-header-wrap th:nth-child(4)').toggle();
$('#grid div.k-grid-content td:nth-child(4)').toggle();
```

or (combined into a single selector):

```
$('#grid div.k-grid-header-wrap th:nth-child(4), #grid div.k-grid-content td:nth-child(4)').toggle();
```

Kendo UI Grid apparently breaks up the table into a structure like this:

```
<div id="grid">
    <div class="k-grouping-header"></div>
    <div class="k-grid-header">
        <div class="k-grid-header-wrap">
            <table cellspacing="0">
                <colgroup>
                    <col />
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="k-grid-content">
        <table class="k-focusable" cellspacing="0">
            <colgroup>
                <col />
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr data-uid="5f65ad8c-601d-4700-a176-23be2d33fc76">
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="k-pager-wrap k-grid-pager k-widget" data-role="pager">
    </div>
</div>
```

As the table header and table body are in different `div` elements, you need two selectors to get them both.

Comment: that can only hide the header, but not the whole column.

Comment: @cool_spirit: If you go to http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html and run `$('#grid div.k-grid-header-wrap th:nth-child(4), #grid div.k-grid-content td:nth-child(4)').toggle();` in the console, the **entire** "Title" column (including the header cell) **will** toggle (which is, in fact, how I tested the above code before including it in my answer).

Comment: and there is weird, i've tried many ways that suppose to work in logic, and in fact it cant work, really upset about it

Comment: @cool_spirit: I noticed you accepted my answer (and thanks!), but your comment suggests that it's still not working. Did this answer provide your solution or do you still need assistance?

Comment: @cool_spirit: If I did not solve your problem (as much as it pains me to say it ;) )then please unaccept my answer and post your own solution (and accept that as an answer) to help anyone else having this problem. Also, Bill Hayden left an answer which references the kendo grid api (and according to the docs, should work for you). You may want to try his solution as well and see if it works.

Answer (score 27):

Assuming #grid is already bound as the kendo grid, you can use the [hideColumn function](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#hidecolumn):

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.hideColumn("CreatedDate");
```

This will hide both the header and data column.  There is also a [showColumn function](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#showcolumn) when you need to show the column as well.

Comment: Clean, simple, and uses the built-in API for kendo. Also references the API. +1 for a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

I show or hide a specific column depending on the screensize.
 
When the screen is smaller as X, the expression gives true.

```
   hidden: ($(window).width() < 1350)
```

(Define in the columns section)

```
columns: [{
    field:  "Answers",
    title:  "Answers",
    width:  35,
    hidden: ($(window).width() < 1350)
},{
    ...
```